Book about a girl with powers and her cat familiar, looking for her missing mom
I'm not sure if this the right place, but I've been trying to find this book that I read in middle school.
I remember it starts with the girl, her witch mom, and the (talking?) cat at home before the mom is swept away by a gust of wind/powers (kinda literally, I think). The girl is left in the "custody" of the mom's familiar who, to shake off suspension, gains a teen human form, naming herself "Cat". I just remember them looking for mom while hiding the magic. Both the girl and the cat befriend the two brother neighbors, who they each strike up romance with. If I remember right, the kidnapper was the girl's dad, who was actually evil or something, and she confronts him in the woods.  (And also, the cat girl was quirky awkward, even licking the face of the guy she liked, because of her lack of social skills).
Please help me because, despite my remembering this many years later, it haunts me that I can't remember/find it.

In roughly which year did you read this?

If i remember right, around 8-9 years ago.
